# zsh local array declaration causes strange behavior

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm new to zsh and have discovered some strange behavior, but this tops it all.

I just came across this extremely strange behavior when declaring a local array in a zsh function that I was writing for my .zshrc file. When I declared a local array it caused my prompt to go crazy. I eventually traced it back to  two very strange functions that randomly got created. I reduced it to a simple case:

```
% function () { local foobar=(); echo frog; }
% echo ${functions[foobar=]}
        echo frog
% echo ${functions[local]}
        echo frog
```

The first strange thing is that `frog` never gets printed from the anonymous function. But the really strange thing is that instead two functions named `foobar=` and `local` get created.

This causes all kinds of problems for my zsh prompt. Whenever the `local` keyword is used it printed `frog`.

I am really wondering what on earth caused zsh to create those functions.

I am using `zsh 5.0.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it must have been a bug in my version of zsh. I upgraded to zsh 5.6.2 and found that the behavior was fixed in that version. I also have a theory as to what zsh was trying to do in the problem situation. When I run:

```
% foo bar() echo hi
```

It creates two functions, `foo` and `bar`, both of which simply `echo hi`.

I think that zsh had been interpreting `local foobar=()` as defining two functions: `local` and `foobar=`. This is really bizarre, as I didn't think that `local` or `foobar=` would be valid function names. I'd be curious to see where the bug was in zsh source.

I also found that the proper way to declare a local array is `local -a foobar`

Comment: How about you accept your own answer, so this question doesn't stay marked an "unanswered"? Thanks!